# String to Int conversion: Convert.toInt16

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, int

This is the code.

```
CODE 1: cmd.Parameters.Add("@RateCenterID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ratecenterid.Text);

CODE 2:  cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuantityThreshold", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToIn32(quantityThreshold.Text);
```

I get the following error in the **CODE 2** but not in CODE 1

Error: **Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.**

kindly help me

Regards,
Arjun

Comment: Isn't the error message self-explanatory?

Comment: Show us value of `quantityThreshold.Text`.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri sample value for "QuantityThreshold = 4036953909"

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Yeah but kindly help me in sorting out this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try entering a smaller or larger value in the `quantityThreshold` text box.

**Update**

Okay, reading your comment response to Saeed Amiri, `4036953909` is too large for an `int` - it's range is `-2147483648` to `2147483647`

You could use a `uint` which has a range `0` to `4294967295`

```
Convert.ToUInt32(ratecenterid.Text)
```

Although you will likely need to change the parameter type to `OleDbType.UnsignedInt` as well.

Comment: ratecenterid is a primary key. It is non- editable plus just read through the label while update action

Comment: sorry I meant the `quantityThreshold` text box; since that's the one you're getting the error on

Answer (score 4):

From MSDN - [Int32 Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx):

> Int32 is an immutable value type that represents signed integers with values that range from negative 2,147,483,648 (which is represented by the Int32.MinValue constant) through positive 2,147,483,647 (which is represented by the Int32.MaxValue constant. The .NET Framework also includes an unsigned 32-bit integer value type, UInt32, which represents values that range from 0 to 4,294,967,295.

You are trying to use a value that is not possible to represent as an `Int32`.

Not sure why your title is about `Int16` as your code and error indicate you are using `Int32` - regardless - [`Int16`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.aspx) has an much smaller range than `Int32`:

> The Int16 value type represents signed integers with values ranging from negative 32768 through positive 32767.

You need to either use `UInt32` or `long`.

Comment: And if it isn't enough, you have another problem with OleDbType.Integer, with the same limitations

Answer (score 3):

> sample value for "QuantityThreshold = 4036953909"

Right. That *wouldn't* fit into an `Int16` (as per your title), which has a maximum value of 32767. That wouldn't even fit into an `Int32` (as per your code) (max value 2,147,483,647). It *would* fit into a `UInt32`, and would easily fit into an `Int64` - perhaps the latter is what you're really looking for?

(You should also clarify your qusetion - are you using `Int32` or `Int16`?)

Answer (score 2):

`Int32` has a range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. You could use a larger type e.g., uint (0 to 4294967295) or long (-9.2233E+18 to 9.2233E+18).

Answer (score 2):

Your current value is within `UInt32` scope, and [`OleDbType.Integer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype.aspx) size is 4 byte and is mapped to `Int32`, if you want use `UInt32` you should use `UnsignedInt` as your parameter type, and use UInt32 conversion:

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuantityThreshold", OleDbType.UnsignedInt).Value = 
    Convert.ToUIn32(quantityThreshold.Text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ref: [Error: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32](http://forums.asp.net/t/1302337.aspx)

> That number is way to big for an int32.  You should just store it as a
>   string.(varchar)

Answer (score 1):

You got the why in the other answers but I didn't see anyone mentioning ToInt64. Simply change the ToInt32 to ToInt64 and also make sure that the datatype of @QuantityThreshold can handle it.

> The Int64 value type represents integers with values ranging from negative 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through positive 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem you will have to put the validation on your textbox - quantityThreshold, it should have the value with in the range of Int32. or use a larger type.